# Conditionally filter using multiple columns if condition in another column is met using groupby method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have df;

```
      ID  YEART   Commdate        Cat  Category
0   LVI6AE2   1993 2017-03-24  LVI6AE2_1        56
1   LVI6BE2   1994 2017-03-24  LVI6BE2_1        67
2   APJ5LEV   1975 2017-03-13  APJ5LEV_1        78
3   LQL0AE3   1986 2017-03-16  LQL0AE3_1        87
4   BLR3UEV   1982 2017-03-15  BLR3UEV_1        90
5   BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-15  BRL1NEV_1        90
6   BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-16  BRL1NEV_1        90
7   BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-22  Ungrouped       190
8   BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-17  Ungrouped       190
9   BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-17  Ungrouped       190
10  BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-22  Ungrouped       190
11  BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-20  BRL1NEV_1        90
12  BRL1NEV   1981 2017-02-01  BRL1NEV_1        90
13  UEE6JSV   2000 2017-03-15  UEE6JSV_1        34
14  UGQ4VE2   1993 2014-07-25  UGQ4VE2_1        45
15  UTU6BE1   1986 2017-03-13  UTU6BE1_1        12
16      NVT   1999 2017-03-10      NVT_1        12
17  OTL3JE1   2001 2017-02-01  OTL3JE1_1        12
18  OTL5XS1   2003 2017-03-01  OTL5XS1_1        12
19  OTL6AE1   2001 2017-03-01  OTL6AE1_1        12
20  JVU6AE1   1999 2017-03-31  JVU6AE1_1        12
21  JVU6AE2   1993 2017-03-31  Ungrouped       120
```

I want to calculate earliest 'Commdate' in each group with a similar 'ID' and 'YEART' only if they fall in ungrouped 'Cat' or Category >100

I have come up with the following line

```
#To Datetime
df['Commdate'] =pd.to_datetime(df['Commdate'])

#groupby
df["EarliestD"] =df.groupby(['ID', 'YEART']).filter(lambda x : x['Category'].count()>=90)['Commdate'].min()
```

The result returns "NaT" for 'EarliestD'

```
    ID  YEART   Commdate        Cat  Category EarliestD
0   LVI6AE2   1993 2017-03-24  LVI6AE2_1        56       NaT
1   LVI6BE2   1994 2017-03-24  LVI6BE2_1        67       NaT
2   APJ5LEV   1975 2017-03-13  APJ5LEV_1        78       NaT
3   LQL0AE3   1986 2017-03-16  LQL0AE3_1        87       NaT
4   BLR3UEV   1982 2017-03-15  BLR3UEV_1        90       NaT
```

Question;

1.Is it possible to conditionally groupby using multiple columns if a condition in a different column is met？ If possible how？
2. Is it possible to call a multiple condition groupby into a `def` function?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `Category >100`, any row in the group with Category above 100?

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo, yes any category with value greater than 100 AND/OR any 'CAT' classified as 'ungrouped'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Boolean filters and `groupby` + `transform`:

```
# convert Commdate to datetime if necessary
df['Commdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Commdate'])

# calculate mask for splitting dataframe
cat_mask = (df['Cat'] == 'Ungrouped') | (df['Category'] > 100)

# groupby uncategorised / category > 100
df.loc[cat_mask, 'Commdate'] = df.loc[cat_mask].groupby(['ID', 'YEART'])['Commdate'].transform('min')
```

Result:

```
print(df)

         ID  YEART   Commdate        Cat  Category
0   LVI6AE2   1993 2017-03-24  LVI6AE2_1        56
1   LVI6BE2   1994 2017-03-24  LVI6BE2_1        67
2   APJ5LEV   1975 2017-03-13  APJ5LEV_1        78
3   LQL0AE3   1986 2017-03-16  LQL0AE3_1        87
4   BLR3UEV   1982 2017-03-15  BLR3UEV_1        90
5   BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-15  BRL1NEV_1        90
6   BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-16  BRL1NEV_1        90
7   BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-17  Ungrouped       190
8   BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-17  Ungrouped       190
9   BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-17  Ungrouped       190
10  BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-17  Ungrouped       190
11  BRL1NEV   1981 2017-03-20  BRL1NEV_1        90
12  BRL1NEV   1981 2017-02-01  BRL1NEV_1        90
13  UEE6JSV   2000 2017-03-15  UEE6JSV_1        34
14  UGQ4VE2   1993 2014-07-25  UGQ4VE2_1        45
15  UTU6BE1   1986 2017-03-13  UTU6BE1_1        12
16      NVT   1999 2017-03-10      NVT_1        12
17  OTL3JE1   2001 2017-02-01  OTL3JE1_1        12
18  OTL5XS1   2003 2017-03-01  OTL5XS1_1        12
19  OTL6AE1   2001 2017-03-01  OTL6AE1_1        12
20  JVU6AE1   1999 2017-03-31  JVU6AE1_1        12
21  JVU6AE2   1993 2017-03-31  Ungrouped       120
```

Comment: thanks @jpp the output doesnt have ‘EarliestD ‘ which I definately need to pass to the next step in my code. Can this be output？

Comment: As per your description isn't "EarliestD" only applicable for ungrouped or category > 100, i.e. 17Mar17 and 31Mar17 for the last 2 rows? You can just rename your column in this case.

Comment: Let me put it this way, I need the earliest date in a group of IDs falling in the same YearT if that combination is ungrouped. For instance rows 7-10 will have BRL1NEV with the EarliestD as 2017-03-17 written against individual rows 7-10  to be passed to next line of code. All rows are individual entities. Didnt make this clear, I am sorry

Comment: 'df.loc[cat_mask, 'Commdate'] = df.loc[cat_mask].groupby(['ID', 'YEART'])['Commdate'].transform('min')' works if Cat is attributed with more than one attriute class. However, it fails if only attributed with 'Ungrouped'.  It throws an "invalid type promotion". To be specific out = np.where(mask, out, np.nan). I am unsure what to equate to np.nan. Any help?

Comment: @wwnde, I can't reproduce. I suggest you ask a new question with data that reproduces your problem.

Comment: worked it out I edited 'df.loc[cat_mask, 'Commdate'] = df.loc[cat_mask].groupby(['ID', 'YEART'])['Commdate'].transform('min')' to 'df.loc[cat_mask, 'Commdate'] = df.loc[cat_mask].groupby(['ID', 'YEART'])['Commdate'].transform(lambda x:x.min())'. This doesnt crash and successfully loads in the next line of code. Thanks